# babel-node fails, when using file's absolute path

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

```
import {
    Observable,
} from 'rx';
import {
  readFile,
} from 'fs';

let readFile_

readFile_ = Observable.fromNodeCallback(readFile)
readFile_(__dirname + '/my-app.js', 'utf-8')
  .subscribe(
    (text) => console.log(text),
    (err) => console.error(err)
  )
```

When i run this ecma6 as `babel-node /home/sk/ws/rxjs-workshop-nov-2015/clcn-app/my-app.js`, it fails with error,

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-cli/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:329
          throw new Error("Couldn't find preset " + JSON.stringify(val));
                ^
Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015"
```

But when i `cd` to the file's parent folder and run `babel-node my-app.js`, it works.

Why does babel-node have this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of Babel are you using?

It looks like you use the latest version `6.0.0` which comes with [major API changes](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/29/6.0.0/). The reason is that Babel wants to be more than only an ES2015 transpiler, but rather a platform.

Anyway, you need specific presets now. `babel-preset-es2015` is the plugin to make it work.

**CLI usage**

```
babel-node --debug --presets es2015 -- script.js --debug
```

**Task runner**

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015` the plugin and add this to your **`.babelrc`** file:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

A list of available presets: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you don't have the preset *es2016* installed globally.

`babel-node` looks for it first in `node_modules` of the current directory, then if there is none, it searches the parent directory and so on, looking at the global `node_modules` as a last resort.